# Question about the integral version of Jensen's inequality.

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

In steele's Cauchy Schwarz masterclass, there is this exercise.
[image]

But can't one just directly apply Jensen's inequality on the convex function $\exp$ and gain the stronger result where the constant $e$ is reduced to one? I think I might be misunderstanding the notation here: isn't the exp applied to the whole integral? Here's the solution from the back of the book.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(7.27) is true without the constant $e$. In fact $\mu(E)=\int_E w(x)dx$ defines  a probability measure and we have Jensen's inequality:

$$h(\int gd\mu) \leq \int h\circ g d\mu$$ if $h$ is convex, $\mu$ is a probability measure and $g, h\circ g$ are integrable w.r.t. $\mu$.